# using sed from a seperate file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a project that I have to use a random number to alter a password. If the number is lower than value given it changes that letter. If it is higher the letter stays the same. My issue is that I am having problems finding information about using sed from another file to change the letter. Now this is not needed, but I feel that it will be cleaner in my opinion. Now my question is how could I call the file from my bash script that will use sed to substitute a letter. I just think sticking 26 sed commands in my script is a little much when I could place it in a separate file. If you know a better way that is fine.

Basic what I need either a better way. Or a way of calling a file and storing sed commands in a separate file from a bash script. And a way to pass just a single character, so if it is the second a in HaloStack, the sec command will not change the first because it would have already been changed possibly.

Below is what I have. I am working on the sed script right now. But I do not know of the way to send it only one character to change.

```
#!/bin/bash

#FUNCTIONS
##Random word grabber
passwdget () {
wget -qO- http://creativitygames.net/random-word-generator/randomwords/$wordamount | grep -o 'randomword_[1-9]\">[a-z]*' | awk -F ">" '{print $2}' > test.txt
}

#parses the words from one file
oneline () {
paste -s test.txt | sed 's/[[:blank:]]//g' > testnospace.txt
rm test.txt
mv testnospace.txt test.txt
}

passwdrnd () {
# Declare array
passwdstr=$(cat test.txt)
}

#VARIABLES
wordamount=4
complexity=0.0

#GET OPTIONS
while getopts ":n:t:" opt; do
    case ${opt} in
        n ) wordamount="$OPTARG";;
        t ) complexity="$OPTARG";;
        \?) ;;#invalad option
        : ) ;;#missing arguments for an option
    esac
done

#MAIN PROGRAM
passwdget
oneline
passwdrnd
echo $passwdstr

exit 0

#Use next information for getting a random number between 0.0 - 1.0
#awk -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed);print rand()}'


#Get position echo ${var:position:length}
```

Sample word list that needs to be altered in different ways.

```
pimplefrogsoapchimp
```

Comment: What have you attempted? Post some of your code. Include inputs, expected outputs etc.

Comment: Asked my question a little premature. I found information on sed scripting and calling it from inside a file. now I was wanting to know how the best way would be to send it a single letter to change.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. That's why I asked for some sample input/output. However, you might want to use `awk` instead.

Comment: I added the code I currently have and a sample of the words that it grabs from a website. Currently I have it put all words on one line. But the issue is I can iterate through the string but what can I do to pass it just that character to the file and then have it overwritten.

Comment: So you just basically need a way to iterate over chars of your string and modify them based on some conditions?

Comment: Correct. My thought process was to iterate through the string one letter at a time. If the condition is met then to pass the character to a sed script that can change it. But if I send it to the sed script I will either pass the entire string, or I will have an issue with it not saving the character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to loop over characters in the password and change them based on some conditions. `sed` might not be a good solution here.

There are a lot of ways to iterate over characters in a string. Using only Bash:

```
pass="somepassword"

for (( i=0; i < ${#pass}; i++ )); do
    char=${pass:$i:1}
    echo "$char"
    #some magic with chars here 
done
```

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' -n 1 char; do
    echo "$char"
    #some magic with chars here
done <<< "$pass"
```

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{
   split($0, chars, "")
   for ( i=1; i <= length($0); i++ )
   {
      print chars[i]
      #do some magic with chars here
   }
}' <<< "$pass"
```

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="" } 
{
   for ( i=1; i <= NF; i++ )
   {
      print $i
      #some magic with chars here (i = char)
   }
}' <<< "$pass"
```

---

Let's say your goal is this simple logic: to change each letter `s` to `b`. You could do the following:

```
for (( i=0; i < ${#pass}; i++ )); do
   char=${pass:$i:1}
   if [[ $char = "s" ]]; then
      newpass="${newpass}b"
   else
      newpass="${newpass}${char}"
   fi
done
```

This simple example can be easily done with `sed 's/s/b/g' <<< "$pass"`. But with looping over all characters, you can do a lot more complicated *logic/calculations*. Using `awk` might give you even more flexibility.

**EDIT:** If you want to just map each character to some different output, use associative array to map them instead. Mapping for three characters, `a`, `b` and `c`:

```
pass="abba"
declare -A map=( [a]="cc" [b]="ff" [c]="rr" )

for (( i=0; i < ${#pass}; i++ )); do
        char=${pass:$i:1}
        newpass="${newpass}${map[$char]}"
done

#newpass is now: ccffffcc
```

Comment: I didn't even think about creating a new variable and just storing it as I pass over each. and that allows me to change. I will still have to have 26 if statements but that works better than what I was thinking. A lot easier also. Thanks.

Comment: @ZerkerEOD Glad it helped. If your logic is just to map characters to some other static output, don't use 26 `if` statements. See my updated answer.

Comment: I did the way you had above before the edit, because we have to do it random to either a Capitol or a special character. So I set an alternating variable, that determined if it was a special and if so it would swap the variable so the next alteration would be a capitol, and vice versa. The only issue I am having now is that my random number has to be a float between 0.0 and 1.0 but I keep getting errors. An arithmatic operator error. with this `code  randomnum=$(awk -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed); print rand()}')
  if (("$complexity" -le "$randomnum")); then`

Comment: @ZerkerEOD `(( ))` can do only integer arithmetic. You will have to use, for example, `bc` to do this, or use `awk` to do everything. And `(( ))` does not really like `-le`. In arithmetic context, you can use `< > <=` etc.

Comment: I am using the `(())` but my issue I believe is I do not know how to store the 0.0 if the user does not define a number themselves. This is my exact error `./passwdgen: line 27: ((: 0 -le 0.330487: syntax error in expression (error token is "0.330487")` I have tried several things but nothing else is helping me. I keep seeing stuff on bc and I am trying to look it up right now. But I used the -le as a last resort, but it is the same error either way. <= didn't work either.

Comment: @ZerkerEOD As I said, `(( ))` can only deal with **integers**. For floating point arithmetic, use, for example, `bc`: `if (( $(echo "$num1 < $num2" | bc -l) )); then ...`

Comment: I did not know how to use `bc` and you helped me. Thanks for that. I was able to get it fully working thanks!

Comment: @ZerkerEOD Glad you worked it out. However, how to compare floats in `bash` is a simple Google search, you may want to try a little bit of that next time ;)

Comment: I wasn't fast enough. I already found the bc part I was just trying to figure it out haha. But you were a lot faster than my google skills lol.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, but if so, this seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash

#FUNCTIONS
##Random word grabber
passwdget () {
wget -qO- http://creativitygames.net/random-word-generator/randomwords/$wordamount | grep -o 'randomword_[1-9]\">[a-z]*' | awk -F ">" '{print $2}' > tes$
}

#parses the words from one file
oneline () {
paste -s test.txt | sed 's/[[:blank:]]//g' > testnospace.txt
rm test.txt
mv testnospace.txt test.txt
}



passwdrnd () {
# Declare array
randchar=255;
passwdstr=$(cat test.txt)
randnum=$(dd if=/dev/urandom count=1 bs=1 2>/dev/null| od -a -i | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}')
chars="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
if [ $randnum -ge 127 ]; then
randchar=255;
while [ $randchar -ge 27 ]; do
randchar=$(dd if=/dev/urandom count=1 bs=1 2>/dev/null| od -a -i | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}')
done;
onechar=`echo $chars | cut -c $randchar`
fi;
#if [ $randnum -le 127 ]; then
#false;
#fi;
}

#VARIABLES
wordamount=4
complexity=0.0

#GET OPTIONS
while getopts ":n:t:" opt; do
    case ${opt} in
        n ) wordamount="$OPTARG";;
        t ) complexity="$OPTARG";;
        \?) ;;#invalad option
        : ) ;;#missing arguments for an option
    esac
done

#MAIN PROGRAM
passwdget
oneline
passwdrnd
#echo $passwdstr
echo $passwdstr
spacing=500;
while [ $spacing -ge `echo $passwdstr | wc -c` ]; do
spacing=$(dd if=/dev/urandom count=1 bs=1 2>/dev/null| od -a -i | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}')
done;
other=`expr $spacing - 2`
fpart=`echo $passwdstr | cut -c -$other`
spart=`echo $passwdstr | cut -c $spacing-`;
echo $fpart$onechar$spart

exit 0

#Use next information for getting a random number between 0.0 - 1.0
#awk -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed);print rand()}'
```

It will use some random to take a character out of what is pulled from wget and change one of them if a random between 0 and 255 returns higher or lower than 127; then it will put the first part in a varaible, a random character in another variable, and the second part in the third variable and print it.